# send data between octave and c++ programm via sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, octave

I am trying to recv data with octave and send data back to a c++ client. It works for the first time.

But if I execute the script in the same octave session again. The client cannot connect to octave. client outputs: connections refused

Octave script:

```
s=socket();
bind(s,12345);
a=listen(s,5)
b=accept(s)
len=255;
data=recv(b,len)
zahl = 10+str2double(char(data))
sendDATEN = "Daten sind da"
send(b,sendDATEN,MSG_WAITALL)
disconnect(b)
```

The client:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    n = write(sockfd,"1.11231231",strlen("1.11231231"));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,100);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Octave seems like the "server" which is always listening and waiting for connections. Your code snippet (from 'b = accept(s)' to 'disconnect(b)' should be in a loop of some sort so that it can keep accepting connections.

Looks like it is executing your script once and then finishing execution.

Comment: connection refused is a clear indication that the other end (server here) is not listening. You can verify the same by the following command netstat -an| grep <your port no>

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you wait some minutes and then try to rerun the Octave server side and the clinet? Then thi scould be a problem that SO_REUSEADDR is missing.

Comment: the problem is in the bind command of octave. So SO_REUSEADDR should fix it. But where can i add this option?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you fail to bind because the address is already in use. You haven't answered my question but I guess you'll be able to connect if you wait some minutes (check the state with netstat!)

There is a for of octave-sockets https://github.com/octave-de/octave-sockets-enh which adds SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG and SO_REUSEADDR